# XmlDocument Replacement

Tags: c#, xml, .net-micro-framework

anyone know of another way of doing an XMLDocument in .NET micro framework? apparently, i am unable to create an XmlDocument object, and so i need to find a suitable replacement. Also, I cannot create an XmlNode object either.

What I am trying to do is grab information from an rss weather feed (XML) off the internet when a button is pressed.

```
//Grab wather data and display useful information.
System.Xml.XmlTextReader WeatherXML = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(http://rss.theweathernetwork.com/weather/caab0211);
System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(http://rss.theweathernetwork.com/weather/caab0211);
XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/rss/channel/item");
string attr = (node.LastChild.InnerText);
```

XML Document:

```
`<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>The Weather Network - Medicine Hat, Alberta</title>
        <link>http://www.theweathernetwork.com/weather/caab0211?</link>
        <description>The Weather Network - ...</description>
        <copyright>copyright stuff</copyright>
        <language>en-us</language>
        <image>...</image>
        <image>...</image>
        <item>
            <title>Current Weather</title>
            <guid>http://www.theweathernetwork.com/weather/caab0211?ref=current_obs</guid>
            <link>http://www.theweathernetwork.com/weather/caab0211?ref=current_obs</link>
            <pubDate>Tue, 20 Jan 2015 11:45:00 -0500</pubDate>
            <description>Overcast, -1&nbsp;&deg;C   , Humidity  72% , Wind  W 18km/h</description>
        </item>`
```

I need that last description (Overcast, -1 °C  , Humidity  72% , Wind  W 18km/h)

Comment: I don't think you'll find a way to load an entire XML document in memory in .NET micro due to memory restrictions. They do appear to provide the XmlReader class you could use to parse the document however: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee437373.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the data from your `XmlTextReader` object, but you'll need to track where you are within the document.

It looks like you're looking for the first `channel/item/description` element. You should be able to use a `Stack` to track your location as you `Read` through the reader.

As a rough outline, push the `LocalName` onto the stack whenever the current `NodeType` is `XmlNodeType.Element`, and pop whenever it's `EndElement`. When it's an element, check whether `stack.ToArray()` matches `{"description", "item", "channel"}`. If it is, you've found the node you're looking for, so take the `Value` property of the reader.

Comment: can't call stack unfortunately, but I have found the following:
    `WeatherXML.Read();
    while (WeatherXML.Read())
    {
         if (WeatherXML.Name == "title" && WeatherXML.ReadString() == "Current Weather")
         {
             rightstring = true;
         }
         else if (WeatherXML.Name == "description" && rightstring == true)
         {
             currCond = WeatherXML.ReadString();
             rightstring = false;
         }
         else
         rightstring = false;
     }`

Comment: now i got to find a way to convert from "ISO-8859-1" to "UTF-8" lol

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment, take a look at the definition of [XmlReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc507042.aspx). If you're wanting to get the value for the the first description element you could get it easily using the following code (as is):

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("http://rss.theweathernetwork.com/weather/caab0211"))
    {
        xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("item");
        xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("description");
        Console.WriteLine(xmlReader.ReadElementString());
    }
}
```

Comment: the unfortunate part is that if you look at the rss feed through the URL, you will see that I'm not exactly looking for the first description element in the document.. Has to be a child of the first channel/item element

Comment: edited my question to make it slightly easier to understand. There are multiple description elements in the xml file, but im not looking for the very first one in the document

Comment: See my edit, it's just an example. You could just as easily loop through read checking each element as well.